# Android- Expecting member declaration error

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class FingerprintHandler(private val appContext: Context) : FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback() {

private var cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal? = null



@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
fun startAuth(manager: FingerprintManager,
              cryptoObject: FingerprintManager.CryptoObject) {

    cancellationSignal = CancellationSignal()

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
            Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return
    }
    manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null)
}﻿}
```

Getting this error while trying to implement fingerprint authentication.IDE is not showing where exactly the error is.

Comment: There's an invalid character after the second last curly bracket

Comment: What invalid character are you referring to?

Comment: It's not visible, if I copy the code into my IDE and remove whatever there's between the last two brackets, it works